# JS object "losing reference" to DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xmlhttprequest

Since yesterday, I've suddenly started to experience some weird stuff involving DOM elements.

The thing is that, on a JS script, I create some constants referencing elements on my HTML document, but when I'm triying to access them (Like updating their `innerHTML` or setting an event like `onclick`) it doesn't have effect; Messing around with the code, I've seen that it seems that they are losing the reference to the actual element. Let me explain myself:

At the end of said JS script, I'm printing an arbitrary const to console, let say
`console.log(resultsContainer);`. And it is actually printing the element, but when I click on "Click to select the node in the inspector" button on Firefox's console, it redirects me to the body tag. Like if the real `resultsContainer` element didn't exist on the document (But it does, I can find it myself in the inspector).

What makes it weirder is that, if I define `resultsContainer` in the exact same way that I do on my script but on the console and then print it, the button now magically takes me to the real element. And after that, if I modify one of it's attributes (like `innerHTML`) from the browser's console, it now reflects do what I want.

It's like when I define them in the JS script they are saved as a previous state of the element, but they are not updating or something.

The way I'm defining `resultsContainer` and using is

```html
<!-- HTML file -->
<div id="resultsContainer" class="resultsContainer">
    <!-- Content -->
</div>
```

```js
// JS file
let resultsContainer = document.getElementById('resultsContainer');

...
resultContainer.innerHTML = 'Some results'; // This is kinda working, see details below.
...
// This prints the element to the console, with the new innerHTML setted 
// before, but it does't reference my HTML element, as the innerHTML didn't change on the page.
console.log(resultsContainer); 

// If I execute this exact same code on console, it does what it's supposed to.
```

I don't really think it has something to do with the way I'm placing the code, as it was literally working fine a few days ago, and I haven't touched these files. (I even went back to one commit from when I'm sure it was working well). But yeah, I'm calling the script at the end of my body tag.

And this is happening to random objects (I mean, they are always the same, but they don't have any correlation between them).

---

Another detail that may help, is that this is happening mainly on JS files where I make XMLHTTP Requests. For example, I define some elements that I want to update based on a HTTP response. If I set the request to be asyncronous, this thing happens and when I update their content, it updates only in the JS object, but not in the HTML page. If I set the asyncronous value to `false` instead, it works fine. But it is not always like that :(. It only works setting asyncronous to false on some cases, but not all, like with `resultsContainer`, as I show below:

```js
const searchPromise: (string) => Promise<Object> = 
    (query: string) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', `/buscar?q=${query}`, false);

        xhr.onload = () => {
            let response = JSON.parse(xhr.response);

            if (response.code <= 0) {
                reject(response.message);
                return;
            }

            resolve(response.object);          
        };

        xhr.send();
    });

const searchAndPopulate = () => {
    const query: string = searchInput['value'].trim();

    searchPromise(query).then(list => {
        resultsContainer.innerHTML = '';
        for (const o in list) {
            resultsContainer.innerHTML += resultView(list[o]);
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        resultsContainer.innerHTML = `
            <p style="padding: 1em;">${error}</p>
        `;
    });
}

let searchButton = document.getElementById('searchButton');
document.getElementById('searchButton').onclick = searchAndPopulate;
```

With this code, when I click my `searchButton` it does nothing. If I execute the last 2 lines on the browser's console, then I can trigger the `searchAndPopulate` function. It makes the petition (Not correctly, tho, as I need the `query` string, but I can't retrieve it unless I define `searchInput` from console, even though that it's defined in the file, but I don't show it here), and I receive the expected response, but then it doesn't reflect on the page, unless I do the `let resultsContainer = document.getElementById('resultsContainer');` on console.

At first I thought that the HTTP petitions had to be the reason of my problem, but as you can see, I can't even set a `.onclick` event.

---

I can do some workarounds, like setting onclick events from HMTL itself and not the JS script, but this started to happen all across my project and without any logical reason. The only remarkable thing that I did was updating Windows 10.

I'm really desperate to found a solution (or at least the reason of this), I'd really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the script loaded before or after the page contents?

Comment: After. When I print some element at the end of the script, it actually prints it out, but when I hover over it on console, it doesn't select it on the inspector nor in the page.

Comment: Don't use `let` for identifiers that will not be changed use `const`

Comment: I'm actually using `const` for all my identifiers, even the ones I show here. I changed them to `let` so I can redefine them from console to make tests. But, originally, they where constants and they were not working that way.

Comment: Wait... is the `searchButton` *inside* the `resultsContainer`?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol No.